# REGEX Pattern help

Tags: php, regex

I want to form a pattern to match the word "Jason" in the following string:

```
[LASTUSER=Jason;22]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following matches the name and the following number:

```
preg_match('/\[LASTUSER=([^;]*);(\d+)\]/', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Doesn't the `^` character mean don't match something?

Comment: It means `Negate this character class`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$pattern = '%\\[LASTUSER=([^;]+?);[0-9]+\\]%i';
if(preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches)) {
    $user = $matches[1];
}
```